# Select items if they or their children match a tag

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to select a list of users which have created a listing item.

There can be parent listing items and children of listing items.

Only results should be displayed which match a certain tag OR if their child(s) match the tag.

I made a simplified reproducible example and had to change the query a little because of `only_full_group_by`.

This is my query at the moment trying to show results that match the tag with ID 3 (tag-c).

This query is not capable of displaying all tags of matched items and its published children. I also fiddled so much around, that ATM it displays child items as results, which is wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `branchid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vid` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO `listings` VALUES 
(1, 0, 'Listing',1,1,1),
(2, 0, 'Listing',1,1,1),
(3, 0, 'Listing',1,2,2),
(4, 2, 'Listing B - Child',1,1,1),
(5, 2, 'Listing B - Child',1,1,1),
(6, 3, 'Listing C - Child',1,2,2),
(9, 3, 'Listing C - Child',0,2,2),
(7, 0, 'Listing',1,3,3),
(8, 7, 'Listing D - Child',1,3,3);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listing_map` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `listing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tagid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO `listing_map` VALUES 
(600,1,1),
(610,1,2),
(632,2,1),
(650,2,3),
(652,2,4),
(653,3,6),
(654,3,2),
(655,5,1),
(605,5,6),
(590,5,4),
(638,6,2),
(601,6,3),
(611,8,5),
(612,9,1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listing_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `title` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO `listing_tags` VALUES 
(1, 'tag-a'),
(2, 'tag-b'),
(3, 'tag-c'),
(4, 'tag-d'),
(5, 'tag-e'),
(6, 'tag-f');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vendors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `title` text NOT NULL,
   `default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO `vendors` VALUES 
(1, 1, 'vendor A', 1),
(2, 2, 'vendor B', 0),
(3, 3, 'vendor C', 1),
(4, 4, 'vendor D', 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO `users` VALUES 
(1, 'user A'),
(2, 'user B'),
(3, 'user C'),
(4, 'user D');
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pMJvDPNqVRhcEhD4U4r3f7/19

If branchid equals zero it is a parent item. If branchid is a number it is a child of the branchid parent item.

There are a few important conditions:

1. Only one tag at a time is being searched. So no need for matching multiple tags (although is would be nice).
2. The results should only show the parent items, even if they don't match any tags, but their child(s) do.
3. The results should show all tags the parent item AND its children (if existent) contain. I have been trying that via GROUP_CONCAT.
4. published state of parents and children should be considered
5. One user is assigned to one vendor
6. vendors that have no listing assigned should get a default result containing their users title instead of the vendors one.
7. If a tag is searched default vendors no longer get a result. So " vendor B" gets a result if nothing is being searched.

Just an explanation:

```
Listing A
- user 1, vendor 1
- no childs 
- tags: tag-a, tag-b

Listing B
- user 1, vendor 2
- two childs 
- tags: tag-a, tag-c, tag-d, tag-f

Listing C
- user 2, vendor 2
- one child
- tags: tag-f, tag-b, tag-c

Listing D
- user 3, vendor 3
- one child
- tags: tag-e
```

Show items matching tag-f:

```
Listing B (tags: tag-a, tag-c, tag-d, tag-f)
Listing C (tag-f, tag-b, tag-c)
```

Show items matching tag-e:

```
Listing D (tag-e)
```

Show all items:

```
Listing A (tag-a, tag-b)
Listing B (tags: tag-a, tag-c, tag-d, tag-f)
Listing C (tag-f, tag-b, tag-c)
Listing D (tag-e)
Vendor D  (no tags, default entry)
```

Thanks

Comment: Added reproducible example via db-fiddle

Comment: Calling somethings tagid (no underscore) and other things listing_id (underscore) is only mildly infuriating.

Answer (score 0):

To recap, here's a query to return all orphans and their associated tags (assuming the hierarchy is only one level deep)...

Note that I'm representing orphans with NULL instead of '0', because that's what I'm more accustomed to, but you can change this back to 0 if you prefer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.id
              , parent.title listing
              , parent.uid
              , parent.vid
              , t.title tag
           FROM listings parent 
           LEFT
           JOIN listings child 
             ON child.branchid = parent.id
            AND child.published = 1
           JOIN listing_map lt
             ON lt.listing_id IN(parent.id,child.id)
           JOIN listing_tags t
             ON t.id = lt.tagid
          WHERE parent.branchid IS NULL
          ORDER 
             BY parent.id
              , tag;
+----+-----------+-----+-----+-------+
| id | listing   | uid | vid | tag   |
+----+-----------+-----+-----+-------+
|  1 | Listing A |   1 |   1 | tag-a |
|  1 | Listing A |   1 |   1 | tag-b |
|  2 | Listing B |   1 |   1 | tag-a |
|  2 | Listing B |   1 |   1 | tag-c |
|  2 | Listing B |   1 |   1 | tag-d |
|  2 | Listing B |   1 |   1 | tag-f |
|  3 | Listing C |   2 |   2 | tag-b |
|  3 | Listing C |   2 |   2 | tag-c |
|  3 | Listing C |   2 |   2 | tag-f |
|  7 | Listing D |   3 |   3 | tag-e |
+----+-----------+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Not getting any results using this query, only if changing form NULL to 0. Also users and vendors table is not included. Tags should be concatenated in results (like describes in question), so only one vendor row is outputted.

Comment: Tags should not be concatenated. That is a display issue, best resolved in application code. And Mike, maybe take a minute.

Comment: That was the question. I need them concatenated.

Comment: Well, my own query was already further to be honest. Without concatenation and solving the troubles around the GROUP BY this is not helping.